# Why is the sample mean the expectation of the empirical distribution?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I came across the empirical distribution $$\hat P(A) = \frac{1}{n}\sum \mathbf{1}_{\{X_i \in A\}}$$today, whose cdf is given by
$$\hat F(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum \mathbf{1}_{\{X_i \leq x\}}. $$
The proof on the lecture notes was
$$\int xd\hat P(X) = \frac 1 n \sum \int xd\delta_{X_i} = \frac 1 n \sum X_i = \bar X $$
I am having a hard time understanding the second-to-last equality.
I know the definition of $\delta_{X_i}$, which is just $\delta_{X_i}(A) = \mathbf{1}_{\{X_i \in A\}}$. But I cannot understand beyond this.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: can I ask from what book is this?

Comment: This is from a lecture note from my statistics class.

Answer (score 1):

There $\delta _{X_i}$ is the Dirac measure at $X_i$ (a random  measure, as $X_i$ is a random variable), therefore
$$
\int f\, d \delta_{X_i}=f(X_i)
$$
for any measurable function $f$. Taking $f$ as the identity function (usually represented by $\operatorname{id}$ or just $x$) you get the RHS.

Comment: Thank you. But why does the equality hold? I don't really know what $d\delta_{X_i}$ means in the context of integration. (I know that $\int f(x) d\Pi(x) = \int(f(x) \pi(x) dx$ where $\pi$ is the derivative of $\Pi$. Is this similar to what we have here?)

Comment: @WinnieXi there $\delta _{X_i}$ is a measure, and $\int f \,d \delta_{X_i}$ is the integration of $f$ against the measure $\delta  _{X_i}$. Take a look at some introductory notes or textbook about the Lebesgue integral to understand how these integrals are defined.

Comment: Sure. I will. I suddenly realized that may be we could view the empirical distriubtion as a discrete uniform distribution on the $X_i$'s. For example, if $X_1 = 0, X_2 = 1$. Then the distribution assigns probability $0.5$ to both $0$ and $1$, and that the expectation of the distribution is the sample mean is pretty straightforward. Is this correct?